# Font installation - mktexmf cannot find newtxbttsla.mf file

Tags: fonts, installing

OS: Windows 7.

TexLive: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX), kpathsea version 6.1.1

I was following rules https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

0. I've updated my TexLive packages from ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final from *TeX Live Manager*
1. I've downloaded newtxtt.zip from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtxtt and unpacked to C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts
2. I've copied C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\newtxtt\tex to C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local
3. I've C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\newtxtt\tfm to C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts
4. Used `mktexlsr`
5. Checked `kpsewhich newtxtt.sty`
6. Used `updmap-sys --enable Map=newtxtt.map`

Running pdflatex for LaTeX file I get

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 1 was incomplete){c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/f
onts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/d
vips/tex-gyre/q-ec.enc}
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+57/600 --dpi 657 newtxbtta

The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexpk

kpathsea: Running mktexmf newtxbtta.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexmf
name = newtxbtta, rootname = newtxbtta, pointsize =
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find newtxbtta.mf .
I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf.
Font resources should be under a directory with the name "fonts".
Furthermore, there must be at least two directories under the directory "fonts".

Invalid path name.
Cannot get destination directory name.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file newtxbtta): Font newtxbtta at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I tried copying `newtxtt` subdirectories directly to `fonts` directory (in `texmf-local`). Same error.

Comment: You can download the tds-compliant `newtxtt.tds.zip` and unzip it at the root of `texmf-local` from [here](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/install/fonts/).

Comment: @Bernard I've downloaded and unpacked. Very similar error.

Comment: The package `newtxtt` is part of TeX Live. Is the issue that it is not in TL 2013 (or not the current version, anyway)? You should consider updating to TL 2014. However, if you don't wish to, I would try disabling the map file, removing all remnants of your manual copying into the tree, unzipping the tds as Bernard suggested, updating the name database, and then enabling the map. [In your original description, you don't say what you did with all the other files from the package, by the way!]

Comment: @cfr: Probably it wasn't part of TeXLive 2013, since version 1.01 dates back to June 1st, 2014.

Comment: @cfr What do you exactly mean by _disabling the map file_?

Comment: @cfr I stated that I manually placed the whole `newtxtt` directory in the `texmf-local/fonts`. Then I manually copied `newtxtt`'s subfolders to `texmf-local/fonts`. Now it's history since i deleted those files.

Comment: No. You only mentioned moving the `tfm` and `tex` stuff. Nothing about the other sub-directories that I could see. `updmap-sys --disable MAPFILE`.

Comment: @cfr I'm sorry. I didn't know. Well, you both helped. Bernard told me to download `tds` font and put it in the `texmf-local`. You told precisely me the  steps I should follow. If it is arbitrary, I would rather ask Bernard for the main idea.

Comment: Ask @Bernard! **

Comment: @cfr: I think it's rather you who helped most, as I am a MiKTeX user and don't know much about the details of a TeX Live installation. I only helped on finding the tds.zip file.

Comment: @Bernard OK. Well, if you're sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be best to think about updating to the latest version of TeX Live. However, if you are not currently able to upgrade, you can follow these steps to install the fonts:

1. Disable the map file:

   `updmap-sys --disable newtxtt.map`
2. Remove all traces of the packages left over from earlier manual installation attempts.
3. Download [the TDS archive](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/newtxtt.tds.zip) as suggested by Bernard.
4. Place the archive in the root of `TEXMFLOCAL`. If you are not sure where this is, get the value using

   `kpsewhich --var=TEXMFLOCAL`
5. Unzip the archive.
6. Update the file name database:

   `mktexlsr $(kpsewhich --var=TEXMFLOCAL)`
7. Enable the map file:

   `updmap-sys --enable Map=newtxtt.map`